# How do you set the value in a key to either of two numbers in python dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, random

Good day everyone, I am trying to set the value of key "Ace" to be either 1 or 11. I mean in different instances it could be 1 or 11. Please how do I do this?

```
cards_value = {
  "Ace": 11,
  "Card1": 2,
  "Card2": 3,
  "Card3": 4,
  "Card4": 5,
  "Card5": 6,
  "Card6": 7,
  "Card7": 8,
  "Card8": 9,
  "JKQ": 10,
}
```

Comment: Can you please give your desire output?

Comment: So I’m supposed to randomly pick two keys and values from the dictionary. I know how to figure that out but at any point that an “ACE” is randomly picked it’s value could be 11 or 1

Comment: Please *update* the question with all **specific requirements**. There is a lot of ambiguity in the question, in its current form.

Comment: Is this for the game of BlackJack, a.k.a. 21? If so, you don’t want a randomized answer for the value, you want to list both possible values (probably as a list or tuple) and choose the value based on the game state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with `random`,

```
import random
cards_value = {
   "Ace": random.choice([1,11]),
   "Card1": 2,
   "Card2": 3,
   "Card3": 4,
   "Card4": 5,
   "Card5": 6,
   "Card6": 7,
   "Card7": 8,
   "Card8": 9,
   "JKQ": 10,
}
```